# How to check with Jest if there is a component inside App.tsx?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I want to know if they exist and if the components below are being rendered in `App.tsx`:

```
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from 'react';

// React Lazy Components
const GlobalStyle = lazy(() => import('styles/Global'));
const Router = lazy(() => import('components/router'));

const App = (): JSX.Element => (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>loading...</div>}>
        <GlobalStyle data-testid='globalstyle-component' />
        <Router data-testid='router-component' />
    </Suspense>
);

export default App;
```

How do I create test quiz?

**Observation:**

I am using the most current version of `React`, `react-testing-library` and `Jest`. I don't want to use the `enzyme`.

Comment: But where is the jsx component? You have GlobalStyles, Router but I can't see any jsx component.

Also could you share your unit test code.

Comment: @Nayanshah 
I want to check if the GlobalStyle and Router exists within the App.